# complex sorting sql

Tags: sql, sorting

I have the following table

```
Priority  Time
100        1
 86        3
 85        2
```

I want to sort it by first by priority and then by time, however, priority differce within 20 points are treated the same. e.g.  100 and 85 are considered as the same priority level.
so the result will be:

```
Priority  Time
    100        1
     85        2
     86        3
```

Thanks,

Comment: The problem I see is chaining. If 100 and 85 are in the same priority, are 67 and 85 in the same priority? If that's the case then you've got 100 and 67 in the same priority.

Answer (score 5):

Try this (assuming that priority is an integer)

```
select * 
from foobar
order by ( priority / 20 ) , -- 0-19 yields 0 , 20-39 yields 1, etc.
         time
```